# How to get QML FontLoader to load UTF-8 on boot

Tags: utf-8, fonts, qml, roboto

My setup:

- Qt 5.9.4
- buildroot Linux system
- rockchip rk3288 processor
- bootscript in /etc/init.d

I have some qml to display some utf8 characters

```js
// roboto font
FontLoader {
    id: roboto
    source: "qrc:/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
}

Text {
    text: "The temperature is: \u2103"
    font.pixelSize: 24
    font.family: roboto.name
}
```

When I run the application from the command line (UART) the font renders correctly.
When I reboot and have my application run from the boot script. The utf-8 characters are NOT rendered correctly.

I have tried all sorts of combinations:

- The font is on the file system
- The font is in different places on the filesystem
- different fonts (montserrat, Avenir, etc).
- display the font based on the loader status == FontLoader.Ready

All with the same results.
I happened to accidentally stumble upon this solution:

```js
// japanese font
FontLoader {
    id: jpFont
    source: "qrc:/fonts/NotoSansJP-Regular.otf"
}

// roboto font
FontLoader {
    id: roboto
    source: "qrc:/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
}

Text {
    text: "The temperature is: \u2103"
    font.pixelSize: 24
    font.family: roboto.name
}
```

This works. I'm not even *using* the japanese font, but it seems to make the Roboto start working correctly.

- Why does my font load utf8 debugging, but not from bootup
- why does this extra font magically fix it ?

Comment: I would check the LANG (and LC_* too) environment variable in both of case. Also the list of available fonts (using QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies)